# Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying moved node-modules and src to client folder and this error occur:

```
'c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ReactCode\soccer-life\src' -> 
'c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ReactCode\soccer-life\client\src'
```

and

```
'c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ReactCode\soccer-life\node-modules' -> 
'c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\ReactCode\soccer-life\client\node-modules'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the mentioned steps

1. Right-click on the project folder
2. Go to properties -> Security Tab
3. Select Users -> Edit
4. In the Permission for Users section, Full control -> Give a check mark in Allow -> OK
5. Wait for Windows security to apply the new security rules
6. Click OK

Comment: How about the Src folder, I can't move it either.

Comment: I have edited the answer I think you don't have admin permission try the above steps for your project folder.